# Are scheduled email reports encrypted?

Tags: commcare

My project uses scheduled email reports to email case lists to field workers, and the case lists include sensitive data. Are the emails and the data they send out encrypted?

Also, can I password-protect the Excel attachments sent with Scheduled Email Reports?

Answer (score 1):

No. You should definitely always acknowledge and evaluate the risks of sending patient-sensitive data over emailed reports.  In this case, it may be preferable to look into only sending de-identified data and/or just sending out a weekly link to CommCareHQ where the data is always available securely.

Comment: @claire The edit was a bit too minor, but I accepted it because there was just the tiniest bit of ambiguity there.  Ordinarily, we'd prefer edits to cover more of the post, but in this case, there wasn't much that needed fixing.